# matrix row-wise lagged differences

Tags: r, matrix

Let´s assume I have the following matrix called **matrix1**

```
      [,1]      [,2]    [,3]    
 [1,] 1.5       1.5     1.5 
 [2,] 2.0       1.7     0.9
 [3,] 2.2       2.3     1.4
```

I want to create a **result** matrix looking like this:

```
      [,1]      [,2]    [,3]    
 [1,] 0         0       0 
 [2,] 0.5       0.2    -0.6
 [3,] 0.2       0.6     0.5
```

Where

```
result[2, ] = matrix1[2, ] - matrix1[1, ]  
result[3, ] = matrix1[3, ] - matrix1[2, ]
...
```

and row 1 is set equal to 0

Anyone have a code for undertaking this operation?

Regards

Comment: if the answer satisfies you, feel free to tick it!

Answer (score 5):

If `m` is your matrix try:

```
rbind(0, diff(m))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]  0.0  0.0  0.0
#[2,]  0.5  0.2 -0.6
#[3,]  0.2  0.6  0.5
```

Another solution - which is in fact a decomposition of `diff`:

```
rbind(0, tail(m,-1) - head(m,-1))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#      0.0  0.0  0.0
#[2,]  0.5  0.2 -0.6
#[3,]  0.2  0.6  0.5
```